# Convert YYYYMM string to date YYYY-MM-DD with day 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this column *Startmonth* from the tables, which is dates liking this: **YYYYMM**, so **201801**, **201707** etc.

I want this column in my view that I'm creating, but converted to a date, like **YYYY-MM-DD** with the day as the first of the month, so **201801 > 2018-01-01 and 201707 > 2017-07-01. **

I keep getting the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Can someone help me out?

I tried this:

```
select convert (DATE, concat (s.StartMonth,'01'), 102) as SubscriptionStart

from incident i

left join imcustomerid cid on i.accountid = cid.accountid
left join billing_subscription s on cid.imcustomerid = s.idcustomer
left join billing_subscriptiontype st on s.idsubscriptiontype = st.id
```

Comment: Are you sure this is MySql?

Comment: Your code works fine for me both with `102` and `112` as the type when using a hard coded string instead of the column (i.e '201811'). What type is StartMonth? Could it contain spaces?

Comment: Note, the `date` datatype doesn't have a format; date(time) datatypes are stored as a binary representation. Your presentation layer chooses the format the date is displayed in (for example, SSMS uses `yyyy-MM-dd` by default for most users).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson nope, no spaces. When I try to convert it with 'from billing_subscription s' (so without the joins) it works just fine, so I don't quite understand why it won't work when adding some joins.

Comment: Add the results for `SELECT StartMonth FROM billing_subscription WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, concat (StartMonth,'01')) IS NULL AND StartMonth IS NOT NULL;`. I suspect your data is not as all in the format `yyyyMM`.

Comment: I agree as well, although style code `102` is defined as `yyyy.MM.dd`, it works for `'100001'` to `'233012'`: [db<.fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=09138b98328add6a411a6b64e80597ee). If we can't replicate the problem, we can't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
select convert (DATE, concat (s.StartMonth,'01'), 112) as SubscriptionStart
```

or

```
select cast(concat (s.StartMonth,'01') as date) as SubscriptionStart
```

[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

I think better to use `TRY_CONVERT` here as said @Larnu:

```
select try_convert(date, s.StartMonth+'01', 112) as SubscriptionStart
```

and `+` instead of `CONCAT` to convert NULL values correctly.

Comment: Still getting the exact same error. They work without the join statements, but not with the joins.

Comment: Try to check `StartMonth + 01` using `ISDATE` - `SELECT ISDATE('20120101'),ISDATE('20121301')`

Comment: The code should work without the style parameter. You simply have bad data... `201913`, `foobar` etc

Comment: @user11299833 - `SELECT s.*
FROM billing_subscription s
WHERE ISDATE(CONCAT(s.StartMonth,'01'))=0`

Comment: Is dislike `ISDATE`, @SergeyMenshov. For example `SELECT ISDATE(2017);` returns 1, but `SELECT CONVERT(date, 2017);` will fail. `TRY_CONVERT` is a far better tool.

Comment: @Larnu - Yes, `TRY_CONVERT` is better.

Comment: @Larnu -  `SELECT CAST('2017' AS date),CONVERT(date,'2017')`

Comment: `2017`, not `'2017'` @SergeyMenshov

Comment: @Larnu - Yes, but in the question it is varchar not int.

Comment: Yes, but my point is that `ISDATE` provides false positives (and false negatives, as `ISDATE('')` returns `0`, but `CONVERT(date,'')` works); just like `ISNUMERIC` does. They should be avoided because they are not reliable. Just because `ISDATE` returns `1` does not mean that the value will be able to be cast/converted, and just because it returns `0` does not mean it cannot..

Comment: @Larnu - Yes, I'm agree with you that `ISDATE` is not a good variant. It's outdated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing a left join on the table with the string which means it can sometimes be null if there is no matching row for an `incident` row and then the conversion fails

Here is one way to solve this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN s.StartMonth IS NOT NULL THEN convert(DATE, concat (s.StartMonth,'01'), 112)
       ELSE null -- Or return some default value, otherwise this row can be removed
       END  as SubscriptionStart
FROM incident i
LEFT JOIN imcustomerid cid ON i.accountid = cid.accountid
LEFT JOIN billing_subscription s ON cid.imcustomerid = s.idcustomer
LEFT JOIN billing_subscriptiontype st ON s.idsubscriptiontype = st.id
```

another is to use TRY_CONVERT instead of the CASE as noted in another answer, it depends what you want to return when null.

Comment: `CONVERT(date,NULL)` returns `NULL`. This won't solve the problem. `TRY_CONVERT` will stop the SQL from providing an error, but may not give the OP the desired results.

Comment: @Larnu Where do I have Convert on a null value?

Comment: To be shorter you can skip `ELSE null` here.

Comment: @SergeyMenshov I know but I thought it would be clearer that you can have a default result. I should perhaps have added a comment.

Comment: *"means it can sometimes be null if there is no matching row for an incident row and then the conversion fails"*. you're saying that `CONVERT` will produce an error if the value to convert has a value of `NULL`; that isn't true. That query will still produce the error the OP is getting as the `CASE` is superfluous. The entire `CASE` could be written as `convert(DATE, concat (s.StartMonth,'01'), 112)` and would be the exact same result (and the would therefore error, as the OP clearly has values that aren't in the format `yyyyMM`).

Comment: Because the problem is the value of `s.StartMonth` when it isn't `NULL`.

Comment: According to OP the conversion works fine without joining , that is converting every row of that column that exists in the table, and that is what I base my answer on.

Answer (score 0):

I think the clearest method is `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(year(s.StartMonth),
                     month(s.StartMonth),
                     1) as SubscriptionStart
```

The more traditional way is just to subtract a number of days:

```
select dateadd(day,
               (1 - day(s.StartMonth)),
               s.StartMonth
              ) as SubscriptionStart
```

I do *not* recommend converting the date to a string for this purpose.  It is definitely not necessary and dates are different from strings.