# SQL Server - Convert number to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that has year and month values together such as 201908. I would like to use this column to filter with regular calendar dates and wondering if there are any suggestions?

Comment: What would that calendar date be for `201908`? Like `2019-08-01`?

Comment: `cast(dt + '01' as date)` might be useful for you. It's unclear exactly what you want though.

Comment: @JNevill Yes, It should be 2019-08-01

Comment: Or split and cast to two ints for year and month that you then compare to your date columns using the YEAR() and MONTH functions.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks a bunch and I should take it from here.

Comment: I suggest you check out this article. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: This has been asked [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704887/convert-yyyymm-string-to-date-yyyy-mm-dd-with-day-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704887/convert-yyyymm-string-to-date-yyyy-mm-dd-with-day-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a static `'01'` to your value and then you should be able to cast it to `DATE` or `DATETIME`:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(10) = '201908'

SELECT CAST(CONCAT(@str, '01') AS DATE)

-- Returns DATE Value = '2019-08-01'
```

or

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(10) = '201908'

SELECT CAST(@str + '01' AS DATE)

-- Returns DATE Value = '2019-08-01'
```